# Content Type picklist values order when uploading to Public Library

Tags: content

When I try to upload file and publish it into a Public Library with Restricted Content Types, the list with available Content Types is displayed in completly random order. Look at the screen:

[image: Content Type Order]

I can't find any option to manage this picklist. I thought that it might be ordered by Created Date or ID and I can make some workaround but...

Name, Created Date, Last Modified Date, Id (all records created and modifed by the same user: Pawel Marszalek)

Termination Notice, 21/08/2012 15:38, 29/08/2012 14:26 00hM0000000NIYc

Contra, 21/08/2012 15:43, 29/08/2012 14:20 00hM0000000NIYh

Intra-Pearson, 21/08/2012 15:59, 29/08/2012 14:23 00hM0000000NIYr

Renewal, 21/08/2012 16:07, 29/08/2012 14:25 00hM0000000NIYw

Deeds, 21/08/2012 16:11, 29/08/2012 14:21 00hM0000000NIZ1

NDA, 21/08/2012 15:13, 29/08/2012 14:24 00hM0000000NIYS

Amendment/Variation, 21/08/2012 15:21, 29/08/2012 14:18 00hM0000000NIYX

Attachment, 21/08/2012 14:38, 29/08/2012 14:59 00hM0000000NIXe

Statement of Work, 21/08/2012 15:04, 29/08/2012 14:58 00hM0000000NIY4

There is no relationship between available Content Type picklist order and these fields.
**The question is - how to make the list to be displayed in alphabetical order?**

Answer (score 2):

Given that content is a sort of 'bolt on' module for the platform I highly doubt that there's anyway you could control this.

They seem to be ordered by `Created Date` for "Termination Notice" through to "Deeds", but there must be some other kind of grouping applied first. If anybody knows the details of the query used—and you can control the relevant fields—then you may be able to control the display, but otherwise I'd say you're out of luck.